# operator = does not work with fstream

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, fstream

I am having a structure

```
struct myStruct {
    fstream fp;
    char *buffer;
    size_t size;
};
```

I am new to C++ and trying to write a code wherein one thread will read from a file into buffer and main thread will write the buffer to other file. The sample of the code is as follows:

```
int main() {
    pthread tid1;
    struct myStruct readArgs;
    fstream fileP, fileP2;
    fileP.open("/tmp/20MBFile", fstream::in);
    fileP2.open("/tmp/trial-file", fstream::out);
    char *buffer;
    readArgs.fp = fileP;
    readArgs.buffer = buffer;
    readArgs.size = 1048576;
    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, Read, &readArgs);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    fileP2.write(buffer, 1048576);
    ......
}
```

The read function is as follows:

```
void *Read(struct myStruct *readArgs) {
    readArgs->fp.read(readArgs->buffer, readArgs->size);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

however, when I compile my code I get following errors:

> error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_fstream& std::basic_fstream::operator=(const std::basic_fstream&)'
>        readArgs.fp = fileP;

AND

> error: invalid conversion from 'void* (*)(myStruct*)' to 'void* (*)(void*)' [-fpermissive]
>        pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, Read, &readArgs); 
>                                                   ^
>   In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:35:0,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/gthr.h:148,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/ext/atomicity.h:35,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/bits/ios_base.h:39,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/ios:42,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/ostream:38,
>                    from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-
>   ....
>   /usr/include/pthread.h:232:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of 'int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)' [-fpermissive]
>    extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,

Am I missing anything here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what can be the solution here..

Comment: The keyword `struct` is optional in  `struct myStruct readArgs;` for c++

Comment: It is declared in actual code, missed while pasting it here. Edited it.

Comment: This is by design, you can't copy assign streams. Move assigning will work.

Comment: I tried with swap() as well but it failed for swap saying   "error: 'std::fstream' has no member named 'swap'"

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `struct`'s members directly instead of creating extraneous local variables?  What is the purpose of the local variables `bufffer`, `fileP`, `fileP2`?  They serve no purpose and your `main` is just doing unnecessary work assigning to them, and then you assign them to your struct's members.

Comment: I guess we cant pass multiple parameters of a function for `pthread_create()`, I want my thread `tid1` to call `Read()`. So bundled all the required parameters for `Read()` in a struct and passed `&readArgs` to `pthread_create()`

Comment: @bhagyeshdudhediya -- You don't need those extra local variables.  Just use the member variables in the `struct` directly (`readArgs.fp.open(...);`)  Second, `buffer` is uninitialized pointer, and your code is attempting to use it in that state.

Comment: Ohh yes, got it. Actually original was a simple code and later I tried using threads in it. The problem of fstream is solved now.
But I still see the pthread_create() error mentioned above.
Am I missing anything there?

Comment: `pthread_create` expects a function signature like `void* Read(void*)`. You can cast the parameter back to `myStruct*` once you are inside the `Read` function.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer..
1. `fstream` - `fstream` cannot be assigned using = but can be moved. `swap()` also didi not work because of the `gcc` version. I have gcc version 4.8.3.x which I guess does not support `swap()` call of `fstream`.
2. `pthread_create()` - it expects function with signature `void *foo(void *)`, so one has to pass the required parameter and typecast it when you are in the required function.
Here I would do it like this:

```
pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, Read, &readArgs);
```

The `Read()` function would be :

```
void *Read(void *args) {
    myStruct *readA = (myStruct *)args;  
    ....
}
```

Thank you all for your time!